# Image is garbled on external monitor connected via HDMI/UDB C adaptor

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi

I have a Lenovo Yoga laptop and am running Ubuntu 20.04. I have an external monitor connected to the laptop via an HDMI to USB C adapter (i.e. USB C on the laptop side and HDMI on the monitor side). The image looks like this:

[image]

Worth noting that if I take a screenshot, the image looks fine. I also know this monitor works with HDMI connected to a tower (with no adapter).

EDIT: The adapter setup does work with a different monitor.

Comment: What is the make/model/spec of the adapter and the monitor? What resolutions/refresh rates have you tried with the working/non-working setup? It may be that the adapter can only support certain resolution/refresh rates or data throughput etc.